# How to use two services in src folder in symfony for same bundle

Tags: php, symfony

```
parameters:
#    b_bids_b_bids_home.example.class: BBids\BBidsHomeBundle\Example

services:

    #    b_bids_b_bids_home.example:
    #        class: %b_bids_b_bids_home.example.class%
    #        arguments: [@service_id, "plain_value", %parameter%]

    b_bids_b_bids_home.exception_listener:
        class: BBids\BBidsHomeBundle\EventListener\ExceptionListener
        arguments:
            router: "@router"
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener,event: kernel.exception}

    app.twig_extension:
        class: BBids\BBidsHomeBundle\Twig\AppExtension
        id:    round_rating_extension
        public: false
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

> i am getting error while declaring two services in same bundle under src folder.I want to use exception listener in symfony

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: nothing but a blank page

Comment: if i remove app.twig_extension . Some pages starts to display 500 error

Comment: I'm not sure if this is copy&paste issue but ``app.twig_extension`` should be intended at same level as ``b_bids_b_bids_home.exception_listener`` - two spaces

Comment: is its spacing issue?

Comment: Switch to the development enviroment (app_dev.php) so you can see error messages.  Debugging blank pages is painful at best.  I'm guessing the 'id:' is the problem.  Never saw that parameter before.

Comment: A YAML file cannot contain tabs as indentation ..getting this error

Comment: Use spaces instead of tabs for YAML files

Comment: Thanks Tomasz Madeyski ,Jason Roman and Cerad! ! That's solves my problem!